# Passing value of Observable to variable in Base Component to child component - Angular 5

Tags: angular, observable, angular5

So I have a base component and in it I have an observable inside its constructor to get a value once it is received inside another component that will validate the user data. However when trying to get this value in the child class the data arrives as undefined. Below the code I'm having problems:

My observable:

```
@Injectable()
export class ObservableUsuario implements ObservableUtil {
    subject = new Subject<any>();
    setUsuario(variable: any) {
        this.subject.next({ text: variable });
    }

    clearUsuario() {
        this.subject.next();
    }

    getUsuario(): Observable<any> {
        return this.subject.asObservable();
    }
```

Here observable has set:

```
 getValue = (refresh: boolean = true) => cacheable(
    () => this.http.get(`${environment.apiEndpoint}/api/Get/Value`, headers()).map(res => {
      this.observableUser.setUsuario(res.json());
      return res.json();
    }),
  );
```

Base component:

```
//more code
       perfilLotado: any;
        constructor(
            public observableUser: ObservableUsuario
        ) {
            this.observableUser.getUsuario().subscribe(
                perfil => this.perfilLotado = perfil.text.lotacaoDTO[0].perfilDTO[0].nome);
        }
//more code
```

Child component:

```
   export class BaseListComponent extends BaseComponent {

        NgOnInit(){}

        validAction(situacao: number): any {
//Here appearer like undefined...
            console.log(this.perfilLotado);
            if (this.sistema.situacaoRestric[situacao] != undefined) {
                this.showMsg('warn', 'Mensagem de Alerta', this.sistema.situacaoRestric[situacao]);
                return false;
            } else if (this.sistema.situacaoRestric[situacao] == undefined && this.sistema.perfilRestrict[this.perfilLotado] != undefined) {
                this.showMsg('warn', 'Mensagem de Alerta', this.sistema.perfilRestrict[this.perfilLotado]);
                return false;
            } else if (this.sistema.situacaoRestric[situacao] == undefined && this.sistema.perfilRestrict[situacao] == undefined) {
                return true;
            }
        }
```

In other words, my problem is loading the value that is passed by my observable to a child component class.
NOTE: From what I understand it is the last component to load, how can I make it load before the other components of the screen?

Comment: try moving the code that subscribe to the observable to ngOnInit

Comment: Who calls " getValue()" and when?

Comment: @Ricardo, i try but don't work...

Comment: @DiabolicWords inside the constructor in base component.When it loads.

Comment: can you include the template content of your parent component ? I will like to see how are you passing the variable to the child

Comment: And when do you call validAction() or better who calls this method?

Comment: @Ricardo The parent component has no template, it centralizes common system functions. I define the value of the variable that I will use in the child component in the parent component.

Comment: @DiabolicWords There is a list inside the base list that defines a datadro action, and in this case validAction () is called

Comment: are you declaring ObservableUsuario in the module?

Comment: @Ricardo, Yes I declare it in app.module

Comment: I believe you should move the subscription to BaseListComponent on the ngOnInit, I don't think is a good pattern have a subscription on the constructor of a service, but I m not sure, If you can, try to push the subcription method to the component and leave the service as clean as possible

Comment: @Ricardo I added the subscribe in ngOnInit, however I still continue with the same problem. The content inside the observable is always the last to be loaded, so whenever it accesses it in the validAction () method it appears undefined, in case it needs to be the first item of this component to be loaded ...

Comment: In my opinon the validAction should read from the observable  of perfilLotado, there you should subscribe and manage your logic

Comment: @Ricardo I just tested your idea, same result. It did not work as it should. It only performs the function when it will load the screen after this it does not access it more the function even when I try to invoke it by an event.

Comment: So reading more here about observable, I believe the error may have been in my logic, since subscribe is only accessed if the change in value of the data occurs, and I'm wanting to access that value after that change has already occurred. I would have to pass this data without being input, because this data is carrergado in another component and keeping it in cache would not be viable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is more or less the same, however, that the data was filled well before this part of the code was executed, so I could only catch it after all the code was executed. Then I was able to solve using the `BehaviorSubject`, setting it together with the other `Subject` no service. Since I need the two in different points, but as a mistake I will have to leave until I solve the problem.

Follow the code i use in observable:

```
@Injectable()
export class bObservableUsuario {

  private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject<any>("");
  currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  changeMessage(obj: any) {
    this.messageSource.next(obj)
  }
```

Service:

```
  GetData = (refresh: boolean = true) => cacheable(
    () => this.http.get(`${environment.apiEndpoint}/api/get/data`, headers()).map(res => {
//for now i need two observers here :(..
      this.observableUser.setUsuario(res.json());
//this bObservable solve my problems
      this.bObservable.changeMessage({obj: res.json()});
      return res.json();
    }),
```

Component child:

```
@Component({ template: '' })
export class BaseListComponent extends BaseComponent {
    init() {
        this.bObservale.currentMessage.subscribe(d => this.perfilLotado = d.obj);

    }
///more code
```

Answer (score 0):

Following your description your problem is, that you subscribe to the service and parallely try to fill in data out of the constructor. You're running in some kind of race condition. I tested it myself. If you'd subscribe out of your constructor but call the service's setUsuario()-method out of ngOnInit() this would be sufficient to have your value present when validAction() is called.

This shortened version of your code works, because the subscription happens in the constructor and the "filling" later in ngOnInit():

```
private perfilLotado: any;

constructor(private observableUsuario: ObservableUsuario) {
    this.observableUsuario.getUsuario().subscribe(
        perfil => {
            this.perfilLotado = perfil;
        });
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.observableUsuario.setUsuario('TEST');
}
```